# sed multiple lines print tab separated

Tags: sed

I would like to use **sed** to extract *index number*, *username*, *IP address*, and *last use elapsed time* from a command output which looks like this:

```
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:lastUseElapsedTime = 214
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:minsToDisconnect = 0
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:sessionType = "tcp"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:serviceType = "smb"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:ipAddress = "192.168.168.1"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:sessionID = 9188440707059155379
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:loginElapsedTime = 3897
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:disconnectID = 9188440707059155379
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:name = "DOMAIN\username1"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:5:flags = 0
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:lastUseElapsedTime = 3772
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:minsToDisconnect = 0
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:sessionType = "tcp"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:serviceType = "smb"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:ipAddress = "192.168.168.2"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:sessionID = 9188440707059155380
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:loginElapsedTime = 3783
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:disconnectID = 9188440707059155380
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:name = "DOMAIN\username2"
smb:usersArray:_array_index:6:flags = 0
```

...and print a tab separated output like this:

```
5<tab>192.168.168.1<tab>username1<tab>214
6<tab>192.168.168.2<tab>username2<tab>3772
....
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -F":| = " '{gsub(/"/,"");gsub(/DOMAIN\\/, "")};$5~/ipAddress/{ip[$4]=$6} $5~/name/{name[$4]=$6} $5~/lastUseElapsedTime/{time[$4]=$6} END{for(e in time){print e, ip[e], name[e], time[e]}}' OFS="\t" file
```

Or by simulating multi-dimensional arrays :

```
awk -F":| = " '{gsub(/"/,"");gsub(/DOMAIN\\/, "")}{id[$4]=1;r[$4 $5]=$6}END{for(e in id){print e, r[e "ipAddress"], r[e "name"], r[e "lastUseElapsedTime"]}}' OFS="\t" file
```

(would love to use this: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html but doesn't work on my awk version)

Output :

```
5   192.168.168.1   username1   214
6   192.168.168.2   username2   3772
```

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully except for some reason it sorts the index numer 0 and 1 rows last. No biggie, though. :)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html . For your case you can use the sort command : `awk -F":| = " '<...>' OFS="\t" file | sort -k1`

Comment: Thank you Corentin! Since the sort field is numeric, sort -n -k1 produces even better results